# Resume code once showing an image in Python

Tags: python, image

I'm currently coding a game and I wish to display an image at the start which shows the map for the game. After displaying the map, I want the game to carry on as normal, however it doesn't carry on until I close the map.

Here is the code in my main() function:

```
current_room = rooms["Reception"]
img = Image.open('map.png')
img.show()
# Main game loop
while True: 
    # Display game status (room description etc.)
    display_room(current_room)

    # What are the possible exits from the current room?
    exits = current_room["exits"]

    # Show the menu with exits and ask the player
    direction = menu(exits)

    # Move the protagonist, i.e. update the current room
    current_room = move(exits, direction)
```

Thanks for any help given

Comment: how to display an image properly depends on the game framework.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.show) for `Image.show()`:

> Displays an image. This method is mainly intended for debugging
>   purposes.
>
> On Unix platforms, this method saves the image to a temporary PPM
>   file, and calls the xv utility.
>
> On Windows, it saves the image to a temporary BMP file, and uses the
>   standard BMP display utility to show it.
>
> This method returns None.

Basically, this method isn't really meant to be used in a particularly interactive way. It *blocks*, which means it doesn't return until you close the application it opened, and hence why your game doesn't continue. There are many, many possible solutions to your problem that will allow you to open the image at the same time as your game runs, but they're somewhat out of the scope of this question, because it depends on how complicated you want to make it (bring in a full windowing kit, or just somehow get it to some other application in its own process that doesn't block, etc).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help
I'll look into these other methods and see if I can find something to work